# How do I put my website's logo to be the icon image in browser tabs?

Tags: html, favicon

The image next to the page title in the browser tab - how can you link an image here?

Comment: Keywords is  favicon.ico

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 255, accepted):

That image is called **'[favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)'** and it's a small square shaped `.ico` file, which is the standard file type for favicons. You could use `.png` or `.gif` too, but you should follow the standard for better compatibility.

To set one for your website you should:

1. Make a square image of your logo (preferably 32x32 or 16x16 pixels, as far as I know there's no max size*), and transform it into an `.ico` file. You can do this on Gimp, Photoshop (with help of a [plugin](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/how-to-open-or-save-as-ico-in-photoshop-cs6)) or a website like [Favicon.cc](http://www.favicon.cc) or [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/).
2. Then, you have two ways of setting it up:

   A) Placing it on the **root folder/directory** of your website (next to `index.html`)
   with the name `favicon.ico`.

   or

   B) Link to it between the `<head></head>` tags of every `.html` file on your site, like this:

   ```
   <head>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
   </head>
   ```

If you want to see the `favicon` from any website, just write `www.url.com/favicon.ico` and you'll (probably) see it. [Stackoverflow's](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d) favicon is 16x16 pixels and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico) is 32x32.

*: There's even a browser problem with no filesize limit. You could easily crash a browser with an exceedingly large favicon, more info [here](https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/apps/a16040/favicon-bug-crashes-browser/)

Answer (score 33):

It is called '**favicon**' and you need to add below code to the **header** section of your website.

Simply add this to the `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/your_path_to_image/favicon.jpg">
```

Comment: I have tried this many times never works for me

Answer (score 14):

This is the [favicon](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) and is explained in the link.

e.g. from W3C

```
  <link rel="icon" 
     type="image/png" 
     href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Plus, of course the image file in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 4):

Add a icon file named "favicon.ico" to the root of your website.

Comment: Remember is has to be **exactly** `16x16`px.

Comment: No it doesn't, it needs to be square-shaped and any size, it'll just take longer to load

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 
'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
```

or you can use this one

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}"
type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: apple-touch-icon is for iOS webApps

Answer (score 0):

1. ADD THIS

```
**<HEAD>**

  < link rel="icon" href="directory/image.png">
```

Then run and enjoy it